# Videoplayer and src outside web folder

Tags: php, html, video

I've got a question for you: I need to place videos played by my website outside the web folder, so that people can't access to them via browser. 
how can I do that, considering that I'm using a html5 based video player (with videojs libraries) because I need the videos to be streamed also by ios devices??? I can't use php scripting for the source because the player can't access to a not-video source.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

If the browser can't access the videos, then it cannot play the videos.

Comment: what about changing video player?

Comment: Good luck finding a video player that can play video you won't send to it.

Comment: I see...is there a method to unable direct browser access to a resource while allowing the access "indirectly" by html, php, js etc (like vimeo does)? 
I've tried using htaccess under apache, but in this way I cannot reach the resource at all!

Comment: No. Leastways, nothing that isn't trivially bypassed.